# Community custom Layout header&Logo

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, napili, lightning-community

How use Company Logo and Header Image in my custom community layout?
I trying add this logo before my custom navigation menu.

[image]

this is my custom layout:

```
<aura:attribute name="formFactor" type="String" default="{!$Browser.formFactor}"/>
<!-- Theme Layout Markup -->
<aura:attribute name="search" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
<aura:attribute name="profileMenu" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
<aura:attribute name="navBar" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>
<aura:attribute name="newHeader" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false"/>


<div>
    <div class="customMenu">
        <c:DTE_CustomMenu />
    </div>
    <div class="profileMenuRegion">
        {!v.profileMenu}
    </div>
    <div class="mainContentArea">
        {!v.body}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find solution without apex.

To display logo on your component when you use napili community template you should add below code to your lightning component:

```
<div class="capricornThemeLayout siteforceNapiliBody" aura:id="baseThemeForm">
  <div class="capricornContainer">
    <div class="capricornNavBar">
      <div class="cBrandingLogo"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

After uploading your image, you can add a CSS rule to reference it with the appropriate scope using the Edit CSS under Branding:

[image]

For the Header Image:

```
background-image: url(/sfsites/c/file-asset/Image_Name?v=1)
```

For the Company Logo:

```
background-image: url(/sfsites/c/file-asset/Image_Name?v=1&height=300&width=300);
```